# awk gzip output to multiple files

Tags: awk, gzip

I can gzip an awk output like this:

```
echo "col1 col2" | awk '{print $1}' | gzip > out
```

But is it also possible to pipe two awk output file streams to gzip? This doesn't work:

```
echo "col1 col2" | awk '{print $1 | gzip > "out1.gz"; print $2 | gzip > "out2.gz"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk, it can handle more columns easily.

```
echo "col1 col2" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i | "gzip > out" i ".gz"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is, and I found the correct syntax, when searching for awk pipe output:

```
echo "col1 col2" | awk '{print $1 | "gzip > out1.gz"; print $2 | "gzip > out2,gz"}'
```