# Splitting out a large file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to process a 200 GB file with lines like the following:

```
...
{"captureTime": "1534303617.738","ua": "..."}
...
```

The objective is to split this file into multiple files grouped by hours.

Here is my basic script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Splitting files"

echo "Total lines"
sed -n '$=' $1

echo "First Date"
head -n1 $1 | jq '.captureTime' | xargs -i date -d '@{}' '+%Y%m%d%H'

echo "Last Date"
tail -n1 $1 | jq '.captureTime' | xargs -i date -d '@{}' '+%Y%m%d%H'

while read p; do
  date=$(echo "$p" | sed 's/{"captureTime": "//' | sed 's/","ua":.*//' | xargs -i date -d '@{}' '+%Y%m%d%H')
  echo $p >> split.$date
done <$1
```

Some facts:

- 80 000 000 lines to process
- `jq` doesn't work well since some JSON lines are invalid.

Could you help me to optimize this bash script?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk solution might come to your rescue:

```
awk -F'"' '{file=strftime("%Y%m%d%H",$4); print >> file; close(file) }' $1
```

It essentially replaces your `while`-loop.

Furthermore, you can replace the complete script with:

```
# Start AWK file
BEGIN{ FS='"' }
(NR==1){tmin=tmax=$4}
($4 > tmax) { tmax = $4 }
($4 < tmin) { tmin = $4 }
{ file="split."strftime("%Y%m%d%H",$4); print >> file; close(file) }
END {
  print "Total lines processed: ", NR
  print "First date: "strftime("%Y%m%d%H",tmin)
  print "Last date:  "strftime("%Y%m%d%H",tmax)
}
```

Which you then can run as:

```
awk -f <awk_file.awk> <jq-file>
```

Note: the usage of `strftime` indicates that you need to use GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this awk snippet, in this related question they don't use `>>` operator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687054/split-access-log-file-by-dates-using-command-line-tools I think this is where the computation cost comes from.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean with _computation cost_. The reason for using `>>` instead of `>` is because I am not aware how many files will be created. If it is only a few files, one can replace the line with `{file="split."strftime("%Y%m%d%H",$4); print > file;}`. However, if it is many files, then you need to close the file and reopen. Hence the usage of `>>` as this appends to an existing file.

Comment: Ok in my initial script there is one write at each iteration of read line. I was wondering if awk did the writes by batch or line by line. In my case I have about 200 files

Comment: In you initial script you read your file `$1` four times. While the complete `awk` script reads it only a single time. I believe that is where most of the speedup will come from. On top of that, in the loop, per iteration, you call sed twice and `echo`, `xargs` and `date` ones each. But these are all binaries which require processing time to load and execute. With `awk` you never do that. That is why the `awk` line presented above will be faster than the while loop, as it mimics exactly what you wrote (including the usage of `echo $p >> split.$date` which in awk is `print >> file;close(file);`

Comment: For 200 files, you can just use the line presented in previous comment. This will be even faster.

Comment: Last question : how does `$4` parse the captureTime pattern ?
Found the answer.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/342842/what-does-this-command-mean-awk-f-print-4

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I told `awk` to use `"` as a field-delimiter. (in the first example using the option `-F '"'` and in the awk-script with `BEGIN{ FS='"' }`. In this case, the `captureTime` is the fourth field, i.e. `$4`

Comment: A great example of replacing many calls to externals (echo, date, etc) and replacing with one call to awk. Good luck to all.

Comment: How can I gzip output files ? I tried to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698296/awk-gzip-output-to-multiple-files but the `awk` syntax is hard.

Comment: @MichelHua : Post a new Q with your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

you can start optimizing by changing this
`sed 's/{"captureTime": "//' | sed 's/","ua":.*//'`
with this
`sed -nE 's/(\{"captureTime": ")([0-9\.]+)(.*)/\2/p'`

> `-n` suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
> `-E` use extended regular expressions in the script